# ID on click to show relevant div id

Tags: jquery

I have a link which loads a popup on click lets say:

and then I have a div lets say

it uses this code:

```
function loadPopup(){  
    if(popupStatus==0){  
        $("#popup1").fadeIn("slow");  
        $("#popup1").fadeIn("slow");  
        popupStatus = 1;  
    }  
} 

$("#link1").click(function(){     
    loadPopup();  
});
```

I only know how to use jQuery click to open the one box when link1 is clicked but if I have multiple links, I don't want to have to create multiple jQuery click links, so is there a easiest way to do it?

I know the above won't work with what I want but don't know how to adapt it to work with multiple links, I have looked on here and found some good examples but can't get them to work.

I want lets say link1 to open popup1, link2 top open popup2 etc etc both being id's

Comment: If you have multiple links, you should have same css class for them. Don't use same id between elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look of an example

```
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link_1" class="linkToClick">Link 1 </a>
          <div id="popup_1"> <!-- your content here --> </div>   

          <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link_2" class="linkToClick">Link 2 </a>
          <div id="popup_2"> <!-- your content here --> </div>
```

Now Jquery code can be :

```
                   $(document).on('click','.linkToClick',function(e){
                         var id = $(this).attr('id');
                         var popupId = "popup"+id.replace(/link/,""); // id.replace(/link/,"popup");
                         $('#'+popupId).fadeIn('show');
                   });
```

You have to make a div respective to each link with common number in id attribute. Put a common class to link say 'linkToClick' in example. Using link id make popup div id and show it.

Answer (score 0):

add same fake css class to the link,then you can use like

```
$(".somecssclass").click(function(){     
    loadPopup();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with it

```
$("#link1").on('click',loadPopup);
```